# How can I make an object move along the vertex of another object?

Tags: animation

I want to make an object move along the vertex of another object. I converted the object into a path and used a follow path, but I didn't move along the vertex and moved along the edge, so I couldn't get the movement I wanted. How can we make it move only along with the vertex?

[image]

This is what I want to make.

[image]

And This is something I've tried, but I don't want to.

Comment: Just ocurred to me, in case of a cube the length of the animation can probably be adjusted so that all frames happen to catch the sphere at the corners...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With animation nodes it is sooooo easy :)

Use this node setup:

[image]

With the B value you can vary your speed.

Result:

[image]

> Note: The advantage of this solution is: Just add two other objects,
> choose these two objects in the node tree and you are good to go. No
> extra work. I appreciate the other solutions...but they are a lot of
> work...

Comment: Nice! I never learned animation nodes, wondering if maybe it's time to do that...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: I just can say from my experience: it is just awesome. One of top 5 add-ons for Blender at all - in my opinion. I just know 5% of it (and 0.1% of Blender) but this is already blowing my mind!!!! Watch the Showreels for it...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB8R_xPpaSc ...if you aren't falling in love with it...i cannot help you. Jacques is a fucking genius. And by the way...that guy is now co-developing geometry nodes...so, i think, there is a lot to come...

Answer (score 6):

Give the object a shrinkwrap constraint.  Target object with the vertices you want to follow.  Set the shrinkwrap constraint to "nearest vertex".  Move and keyframe the object; you'll see that it snaps to the nearest vertex of the object you've designated.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's a hacky solution, it relies on the order in which modifiers are evaluated, and it produces an error for the first vertex...

Name your Cube **Main**. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it. Hide **Main** and name the copy **Instancer**. <kbd>Tab</kbd> and in *Edit Mode* select everything if it's not selected already, <kbd>X</kbd> Delete, <kbd>O</kbd> Only Edges and Faces. Add a vertex group and assign all vertices to it. <kbd>Tab</kbd> in *Object Mode* add *Build* modifier, set its length to the number of vertices (8 for a cube) and set scene's frame end to the same number.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to make a linked copy of the **Instancer**. Name the copy **Mask** and hide it. Select the **Instancer** again, set *Build's* modifier starting frame to 0. Add *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier, set the vertex group, the target to **Mask** and *Proximity Mode* to **Geometry**. Add *Mask* modifier and set the vertex group.

In *Object Properties > Instancing* choose *Vertices*. Create a UV Sphere and parent it to the **Instancer**. Hide the **Instancer** and unhide **Main**. In the outliner, disable rendering of all currently hidden objects.

[image]

One corner is being missed... A workaround: select **Instancer** <kbd>Tab</kbd> for Edit Mode, <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>Right Click to create a new vertex, menu *Mesh > Sort Elements > Selected* to put it in front, also increase the Build modifiers lengths by 1 (to 9 in case of the cube) and decrease their start by 1 (to -1 and 0).

[image] [image]

Replacing with a more complex object is surprisingly easy: delete **Main**, insert the new object (I added Suzanne), select **Instancer**, in *Object Data Properties* switch the mesh to the new **Main's** mesh, make a single-user copy, remove edges and faces, add a vertex, move it in front, use statistics to count vertices, update the Build Modifiers length and scene.frame_end, change **Mask's** mesh to the same the **Instancer** uses. Done.

[image]

Comment: Man...you are just toooo intelligent. You missed the easy solutions :) +1 but i love hacky... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do that is by giving a keyframe for each location by snapping the sphere to the cube vertices in the viewport.

Then on the *Timeline* from the animation menu selecting all the keyframes pressing <kbd>T</kbd> and setting the interpolation to **Constant**.

Also here is the blend file:

[image]