# How do I create an animation that moves along the vertex using an animation node?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

Last time I asked how to make an animation that moves along the vertex, thankfully I learned how to use an animation node ([How can I make an object move along the vertex of another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/244287/136138)),

But is there a way to make the animation below using the animation node?

[image: ani]

- Each time the camera rotates along the vertex, the light source moves
  to the next vertex.
- The camera repeats movement until the light
  source reaches all the vertices.

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to make it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup to achieve your goal:

[image]

Basically it is the same as last time, just a bit more math.

Instead of moving 1 step per frame, i use the modulo so that it repeats it pattern. e.g.

```
frame modulo 2
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    0

frame modulo 3
    1    1
    2    2
    3    0
    4    1
    5    2
    6    0
```

so basically modulo repeats counting from 0 to modulo value - 1 if modulo is an integer.

By this i got that repeating (neverending pattern).

for the direction of the sun i just used a track to constraint, which tracks to an empty on 0,0,0. Same with the camera, which tracks to suzanne.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted!!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome